# I get "SafeERC20: low-level call failed" error in the OKX Aggregation Router contract

Tags: erc-20, gas, gas-price, wagmi, viem

I am developing a swap application using an OKX dex api in my project where I use Nextjs typescript. Documentation: https://www.okx.com/tr/web3/build/docs/waas/dex-swap
According to this documentation, I pass the relevant parameters to the swap endpoint. And it returns me two objects: dexRouterList and tx. I send the "data" in this tx object to the OKX Aggregation Router contract with the wagmi hook useSendTransaction. But the process fails and I get the bscscande SafeERC20: low-level call failed error. Agreement on the BSC network: https://bscscan.com/address/0x9333c74bdd1e118634fe5664aca7a9710b108bab

**I pass the tx data returned from the swap API to the ApproveOrReviewButton component through the calldata state. calldata, that is, the content of the tx data**

```
data:"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"
from: "0xEb218F28ACEea78E20910286b1Acfef917A270Ab"
gas: "202500"
gasPrice: "3376409815"
maxPriorityFeePerGas: ""
minReceiveAmount:"22318230932688456759"
to: "0x9333C74BDd1E118634fE5664ACA7a9710b108Bab"
value: "0"
```

```
function ApproveOrReviewButton({
  takerAddress,
  sellTokenAddress,
  fromTokenAddress,
  dexAdress,
  amount,
  geckoId,
  slippage,
  calldata,
  web3,
  estimateGasFee
}: {
  takerAddress: Address;
  sellTokenAddress: Address;
  fromTokenAddress:Address;
  dexAdress:Address;
  amount: any;
  geckoId:any;
  slippage:any;
  calldata:any;
  web3:any;
  estimateGasFee:any;
}) {

  const { data: allowance }:any = useReadContract({
    address: sellTokenAddress,
    abi: abi,
    functionName: "allowance",
    args: [takerAddress, dexAdress],
  });

  const simulate:any = useSimulateContract({
    address: sellTokenAddress,
    abi: abi,
    functionName: "allowance",
    args: [takerAddress, dexAdress],
  });

  const {
    data:writeContractResult,
    writeContractAsync:approveAsync,
    error,
  }:any = useWriteContract();


  const { isLoading: isApproving , error:approveError }:any = useWaitForTransactionReceipt({
    hash: writeContractResult ? writeContractResult : undefined,
    onSuccess(data:any) {
      console.log("SUCCESS",data)
    },
  }as any);

  console.log("writeContractResult",writeContractResult)

  const {data:pretransac,config}:any = usePrepareTransactionRequest({
    data: calldata.data, 
    account: takerAddress,
    to: calldata.to,
    gas: calldata.gas,
    gasPrice:calldata.gasPrice,
    value:calldata.value
  })

  console.log("pretransac",config) //undefined

  const { 
    sendTransactionAsync,
    data:swap,
    error:swapError,
    status 
  }:any = useSendTransaction(config)

  const { isLoading, isSuccess } = useWaitForTransactionReceipt({
    hash: swap ? swap : undefined,
  })


  const handleSwapR = async () => {
    
    const swaps:any = await sendTransactionAsync({
      data: calldata.data,
      to: calldata.to,
      gas:calldata.gas,
      gasPrice:calldata.gasPrice,
      minReceiveAmount:calldata.minReceiveAmount,
      value:amount, //50000000000000000
    })
    console.log("swaps",swaps)
  }

  if (error || approveError) {
    return <div className="whitespace-pre-wrap h-32 w-96 overflow-y-auto overflow-x-hidden mt-10">Something went wrong: {error.message}</div>;
  }
  //@ts-ignore
  if (allowance === 0n ) {
    return (
      <>

        <button
          type="button"
          className="border border-transparent hover:border-white hover:border-opacity-10 w-full rounded-xl flex justify-center items-center bg-fuchsia-800 bg-opacity-30 hover:bg-opacity-100 p-3 transition-all text-neutral-400 hover:text-neutral-200"
          onClick={async () => {
            // const writtenValue = await approveAsync();
            await handleSwapR()
          }}
        >
          {isApproving ? "Approving…" : "Approve"}
        </button>
        
      </>
    );
  }

  return (
    <button
      type="button"

      className="border border-transparent hover:border-white hover:border-opacity-10 w-full rounded-xl flex justify-center items-center bg-fuchsia-800 bg-opacity-30 hover:bg-opacity-100 p-3 transition-all text-neutral-400 hover:text-neutral-200"
    >
      Insufficient Balance
    </button>
  );
}
```